# tokenizing a list doesn't work with UTF8

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, text2vec

I extract some data from Oracle DB to do some text mining. My data is UTF8 and vocab can't handle it.

```
library(text2vec);
library(DBI);
Sys.setenv(TZ="+03:00");
drv=dbDriver("Oracle");
con=dbConnect(drv,username="user","pass",dbname="IP:port/servicename");

list=dbGetQuery(con,statement = "select * from test");

it_list = itoken(list$FNAME, 
                  preprocessor = tolower, 
                  tokenizer = word_tokenizer, 
                  ids = list$ID, 
                  progressbar = FALSE);

vocab = create_vocabulary(it_list, ngram = c(ngram_min = 1L, ngram_max =2L));
```

but just English word exists in vocab.

- list variable object exists in this [link](http://myonlineclass.ir/test/obj_list) (can be loaded with `load()`)
- I use windows
- R.version:

> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>       arch           x86_64
>       os             mingw32
>       system         x86_64, mingw32
>       status
>       major          3
>       minor          3.0
>       year           2016
>       month          05
>       day            03
>       svn rev        70573
>       language       R
>       version.string Oracle Distribution of R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
>       nickname       Supposedly Educational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This is actually an issue with `base::strsplit()` which is used for basic tokenization.

I suggest you to use [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) package for regex with strong UTF-8 support. Or simply use [tokenizers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tokenizers/) - good solution for tokenization on top of `stringi`.

For example you can use `tokenizers::tokenize_words` as drop-in replacement of `word_tokenizer`

```
tokenizers::tokenize_words("پوشاک بانک لي ")
# "پوشاک" "بانک"  "لي"
```

For some reason `base::strsplit()` doesn't consider theses arabic symbols as "alphanumeric" (`[[:alnum:]]`).

```
strsplit("i was. there", "\\W") %>% lapply(function(x) x[nchar(x) > 0])
# "i"     "was"   "there"
strsplit("پوشاک بانک لي ", "\\W") %>% lapply(function(x) x[nchar(x) > 0])
# character(0)
```

Comment: That is Persian symbols :)

Comment: but alphabet is the same, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, it's different like German and English alphabet.